# When is Automatic Re-buy Triggered?

Tags: online, rules

In online poker rooms, before I sit down on a table, the buy-in popup appears. One of the options is to automatically buy-in once I'm out or low on chips.

The question I have is, does this feature trigger at the end of the game/hand (ie. showdown, all players folded except 1), *or* does it happen at the end of the round (flop,river...).

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Felipe, I just wanted to mention something about this type of question. A question like this is probably better suited to asking in the "Chat" function. I've no doubt you'd get a quick response about this sort of thing.

Comment: @Felipe, I doubt that there are any rules that allow you to get money into your stack during a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for most Poker rooms it triggers at the end of the hand just before a new hand starts